# How to track from button click on website of app through Google Play up to in-app purchase in Android app?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I would like to get information: How many people who went through the app website made an in-app purchase?

Funnel: Click to "Get it on Google Play" button on the website of app > install app via Google Play > in-app purchase in Android app.

Android app uses Firebase SDK. (I am advanced.)
App website uses Google Analytics v4. (I am beginner -- I set it up yesterday.)

Is it possible to connect/keep tracking from website of app via Google Play to Android app?

It would be great to see in Google Analytics: n% of people made in-app purchase after click to Download button on app website.
or
The similar information in Firebase.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution for your purpose is to handle [Dynamic Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links) with Deep link

declare your app launcher can open some dynamic link, e.g. `yourapp://tracking.key/` (so also `yourapp://tracking.key/<secret_key>`)

then construct dynamic link (e.g. [manually](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually)), which will pass user to Play Store if app not installed. after installation and "Open" button press app will be opened with your deep link in intent and then you have "connection" between web click (cookie) and installed app (`<secret_key>`). then just track in app purchases reporting also obtained in app `<secret_key>`

if you don't want such precision you may just declare deep link as follow: `yourapp://tracking.key/web_click`